# Pycrypto 2.6.1 for android smartphone

Tags: android, encryption, smartphone, pycrypto, qpython

I am doing a project where I am required to do an encryption on Windows system and then I need to decrypt the message on an Android smartphone. I am using Python with pycrypto 2.6.1 module on Windows and qpython app on the smartphone. Qpython is not recognizing the the encryption code I am using on Windows and it is telling me that no module Crypto can be found. How do I implement pycrypto 2.6.1 module on smartphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pycryptodome-qpython3` from QPyPI on QPython3L.
Right now, the only working package similar to `pycrypto` is `pycryptodome-qpython3` on QPyPI.
And it only works on QPython3L.

- [QPyPI pycryptodome-qpython3](https://qpypi3.qpython.org/pyshop/package/pycryptodome-qpython3)
- [QPyPI file pycryptodome-qpython3-3.8.1.tar.gz](http://pypi3.qpython.org/repository/129423/pycryptodome-qpython3-3.8.1.tar.gz#6b29d6800113433924b1afeadc986fab)

(I shared a Crypto.zip on Google drive before.
That's an ancient pycrypto 2.5, working on ancient Python 2, on ancient QPython v1.3.2.
I don't think any people would still need the ancient version.)